# centos login in the first time

Tags: linux, centos, login

I'm a beginner to play Linux. And I've installed Centos into the VMware.

However, after I set the settings, the windows run the all black window and ask me to login. Of course, I key my account and push "Enter". But, when it comes to "password" and I can't input anything to the line. Hence , I assume that "can't input any words" as a mask to protect. But, no matter how many times I try it, I can't start my first step to Linux. Please help me.

And the Problem is in these pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just to note: when you are typing a password in the console - there won't be any asterisks on the screen

Comment: You're trying to a text-only server? Or is your GUI not starting? Did you follow a guide like from here https://www.centos.org/docs/5/ maybe an Installation guide? Looks to be Red Hat based, so uses their guides too.

Comment: @ALex_hha even though i have typed correct password , I can't login the system. And I've reinstalled and set the account again to solve it . However, it's not helpful on the problem(in this command line)

Answer (score 1):

It's too early for you to learn Linux on the command line interface (aka black screen). Soon you will face even more mysterious situations and you seem not to have guts to experiment quickly. You need more experience with various programs to gain some basic courage. You can obviously try more user-friendly distributions of Linux (maybe Ubuntu?).

The answer is: just type the password with your keyboard and press Enter. Ignore the apparent lack of dots/stars/cookies.

Linux systems at all times distinguish between lower vs upper case of letters in file names, logins, passwords, and most other textual input - passWORD is different than PASSword and PASSWORD.

Comment: Hi,in the first , thank for your help. in the fact , I am a undergraduate and study in software engineering. But, I just want learn more about these. Back to your answer, I've done your advice  before I post this problem. And even I reinstall it twice and be sure the account and password is correct. But, after all, I get the error feedback .

Comment: Keep an eye on lower vs upper case - passWORD is different than PASSword and PASSWORD.